# La función SUM de MySQL no me devuelve nada

Tags: php, mysql

En esta consulta pretendo sumar el total de agua de una base de datos:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");//Convertim a JSON
require_once("../connect.php");//Connectem amb la BBDD
$db = new Conexion();

$user = $_GET["iduser"];
$dbWater = 'r_water';
$consulta = "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM $dbWater WHERE id_user = $user";
$result = $db->prepare($consulta);
$result->execute();

if (!$result){ 
    print "<error>Error en la consulta.</error>\n";
}else{
    $water = array();
    foreach($result as $valor){
        $arr = array(
            'amount' => $valor['amount']);
        array_push($water, $arr);
    }

    echo json_encode($water);
}
$db=NULL;
```

En el JSON me sale `[{"amount]:null}]`, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: En ese trozo de codigo, la asignacion de 'amount' es de la variable **$valor['amount']**, que no esta definida en tu codigo... revisa eso.

Comment: Perdon, me havia dejado el foreach($result as $valor).

Comment: ok. Tiendo a pensar que el error es el indice de $valor. prueba primero con un var_dump($result) al principio del else, para ver que indices tienes en esa variable. ademas, en tu consulta devuelves "Select SUM(amount)", no un campo llamado **"amount"**. Si acaso, puedes hacer **"Select SUM(amount) as sum_amount"**, y probar a asignar con **$valor['sum_amount']**

Comment: Varias cosas: 1. No estás manejando los datos de forma segura, debes usar consultas preparadas en vez de pasar el valor obtenido en el GET junto con la cadena SQL.  2. Si usas PDO o MySQLi, puedes obtener tu resultado en un array usando FETCHASSOC, en vez de tratar tú de construirlo como veo que estás haciendo. 3. No tiene ningún sentido que pases el nombre de la tabla en una variable, eso no te protege de nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no me equivoco te está dando `null` porque no está encontrando `$valor['amount']` ya que no hay un campo "amount".

Para que te devuelva el valor que quieres recoger yo renombraría el resultado de la consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
SUM(amount) AS suma
```

quedando el código de la siguiente forma utilizando consultas preparadas para mejorar la seguridad:

```
$consulta = "SELECT SUM(amount) AS suma FROM r_water WHERE id_user = ?";

$result= $db->prepare($consulta);
$result->bind_param("i", $user );

$result->execute();

if (!$result){ 
    print "<error>Error en la consulta.</error>\n";
}else{
     $water = array();
     foreach($result as $valor){
        $arr = array(
            'amount' => $valor['suma']);
        array_push($water, $arr);
     }

     echo json_encode($water);
}
$db=NULL;
```

En el caso que utilices **MySQLi** o **MySQL PDO** podrías utilizar la siguiente función para recoger tu resultado y pasarlo a json:

```
$water = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($water );
```

Comment: Exacto! Ya me havia dado cuenta hace nada, pero gracias por la respuesta igualmente. :)

Comment: de nada @KikuS. me alegro que te haya servido

Comment: @Pikoh he puesto el foreach porque era como lo tenia el OP, he intentado cambiar lo menos posible su código, pero tienes razón la consulta sólo debuelve un valor

Comment: Insisto en que la solución no es óptima. 1º. Porque preserva una consulta vulnerable de **Inyección SQL**. 2º. Porque reinventa métodos que ya existen para almacenar en un arreglo los resultados.

Comment: @A.Cedano he modificado mi respuesta teniendo en cuenta lo que señalabas, como no se si utiliza MySQLi o MySQL PDO he dejado el foreach, sino se podria utilizar la función `mysqli_fetch_all`. Gracias por tu observación